# How do I enable certain services in Safe Mode?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, printing, speakers, safe-mode

I have a Windows Vista computer that is no longer functioning properly on regular mode, however it works okay on Safe Mode with Networking. I'd like to enable some other services on Safe Mode though, such as the print spooler and the volume. I attempted to create a registry file to enable printing. The contents of it is below:

```
Windows Registry Editor 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network\Spooler]
@="Service"
```

When I ran this, it successfully added the entry, and I restarted, but I still am unable to print. When I try to do it, the only option available is to save the page to a PDF. The computer is showing that no printers are connected. How can I get some of these services to startup with Safe Mode? I'm most interested in the print spooler and the speakers.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www.bookingtohosting.com/2015/02/how-to-start-windows-audio.html)

Comment: Yes. It didn't work. I typed the following commands: "REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network\Spooler" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service" which was successful. Next, I type "net start spooler" which responds with "System error 1068 has occurred. The dependency service or group failed to start."

Comment: spooler depends on rpc and http.sys driver. make sure they are running

Comment: RPC is running according to services.msc, but not the RPC locator. When I try to run that, it tells me that it can't be started in Safe Mode. I can't find the other service anywhere. How exactly do I start these?

Comment: Did you start in safe mode With networking, you must for the print spooler to work.